# Tailwind class not working in production with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

For some reason, `col-start-n` doesn't seem to be working in the production version of my code. If I run it locally, I get the expected result which is 2 cards in 2 different rows, like so:
[correct placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/537C1.png)

When I run it with `yarn serve -mode production`, I get them in the same row, with the top of one slightly below the other:
[incorrect placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJoMl.png)

This is the code snippet where I'm running into an issue. I've even tried directly editing the value for `col-start-n` directly when inspecting the element, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<div class="flex-grow flex-col overflow-auto max-h-screen w-full dark:text-gray-300 main-body">
  <div class="m-auto pt-4 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-8 space-y-12">
    <div class="h-64 max-h-screen lg:col-span-4 lg:col-start-3">...</div>
    <div class="h-64 max-h-screen lg:col-span-4 lg:col-start-3">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my tailwind configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        nunito: ['nunito', 'sans'],
        cinzel: ['cinzel', 'sans-serif'],
        lora: ['lora', 'sans-serif']
      },
      listStyleType: {
        square: 'square'
      },
      boxShadow: {
        'sm-white': '0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)',
        white: '0 1px 3px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)',
        'md-white': '0 4px 6px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)',
        'lg-white': '0 10px 15px -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)',
        'xl-white': '0 20px 25px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04)',
        '2xl-white': '0 25px 50px -12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)',
        '3xl-white': '0 35px 60px -15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
        'inner-white': 'inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)'
      }
    },
    container: {
      center: true
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      boxShadow: ['dark']
    }
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `flex` classes only , you don't need to use `grid` classes then.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex-grow container mx-auto flex-col justify-center overflow-auto max-h-screen  dark:text-gray-300 ">
  <div class="m-auto pt-4 space-y-12">
    <div class="h-64 max-h-screen  bg-slate-200 text-center p-10">Card 1</div>
    <div class="h-64 max-h-screen  bg-slate-300 text-center p-10">Card2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it looks like that only works if I remove the `flex` option from my `#app` div, which of course subsequently breaks my footer sticking to the bottom of the page. I'm still confused why the grid option works locally but breaks when running in production mode.